# EFCore Identity: Admin Razor Page : create user with roles

Tags: identity, model-binding, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to create a Razor Page for an admin to add a user with checkboxes to select the roles for the user. But i'm not getting the desired result.

Pagemodel:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public InputModel Input { get; set; }

public class InputModel
{
  public string Email {get; set;}
  ...
  public list<rol> rollen {get;set;}
}
public class rol
{
  public string name {get;set}
  public bool selected {get;set;}
}
```

In the OnGet():

```
Input.rollen = (from rol in _roleManager.Roles
  select new rol
  {
    name = rol.Name,
    selected = false
  }).ToList();
```

In the Page:

```
@foreach (var rol in Model.Input.rollen.OrderBy(x=>x.name))
{
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="@rol.name" name="@rol.name">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="@rol.name">
      @rol.name
    </label>
  </div>
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Visually it gives the correct result. But off course when posting the form, it doesn't match the model. What is the correct way of doing this? I could just add the checkboxes manually, one by one but that's not really the way of doing things

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer using thins page: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes.

I added

```
[BindProperty]
public InputModel Input { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public List<string> roles { get; set; }
```

Onget:

```
public void OnGet()
{
  var rollen = _roleManager.Roles.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
  ViewData["roles"] = roles;
}
```

On page:

```
    <div class="form-row">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Rollen</label>
        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            @foreach(var role in ViewData["roles"] as List<string>)
            {
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="roles" value="@role">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    @role
                </label>
              </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

On Post you get the List which contains all the **checked** values. It's important that all checkboxes have the same name-attribute

I found that page before but i just didn't get it to work. But that was because i added the List as part of the InputModel. I had to add it as Bindproperty separatly.